# want to display a json data using jquery in my html input field

Tags: jquery, html, json

been trying to get the JSON data to display in my HTML page input field but it does not display will the JSON file is connected because if I use console.log I can see my JSON data in console section in the browser. and it says same is undefined please someone helps it been 2days now.

and using visual studio 2019 with an asp.net core MVC, I am new to it still learning jquery bit by bit

```
var uri = "../view-resources/Views/Occupant/dataroom.json?nin=" + nin
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: uri,
        contentType: "application/json",
        error: function () {
            $('#loadingid').addClass('hidden');
            $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'none');
            swal("Oops!", "Error! Contact support", "error")
                .then(() => {
                    $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'block');
                });
        },

        success: function (response) {           
            console.log(response);

            if (nin == "00123456789") {
                var result = response.result;

                $("#sName").val(result.sName);
                $("#fName").val(result.fName);
                $("#mName").val(result.mName);
                $("#formno").val(result.formno);
                $("#sCode").val(result.scode);
            }
            else {
                $('#loadingid').addClass('hidden');
                $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'none');
                swal("Oops!", "Recorde Not Found!!", "error")
                    .then(() => {
                        $('#containerDiv').css('display', 'block');
                    });
            };
        }
    });
}
```

the input fields should display the following json when page load

```
{
  "nin=00123456789": 
    {
      "sName": "First",
      "fName": "Second",
      "mName": "Third",
      "formno": "12345678900",
      "sCode": "14577892"
    }
}
```

Comment: it'd be better if you add your `HTML` code. Also, try to clarify more your issue and that `min` variable.

Comment: If `sName` is undefined in the json you receive, look at the server script, because it's not outputting sName somehow.

Comment: <div class="col-md-4">
 <b>Middle Name </b><i class="fa fa-pencil edit-icon hidden"></i>
  <div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-addon">
  <i class="material-icons">account_circle</i>
  </span>
  <div class="form-line">
  <input type="text" id="mName" class="form-control input-edit" disabled>
   </div>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

Comment: ok then will check but want to know the jquery code for the connection of the field is right

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. Note that if the JSON received is as you've shown at the bottom, `response.result` is likely undefined. You probably want to use `console.log(JSON.stringify(response))` to see what you're getting there.

Comment: thanks, ya all for commenting I got my mistakes